# Runing Wordpress on my wampserver localhost error?

Tags: wordpress, wampserver

I just downloaded WordPress and extracted it's WordPress folder to my wamp-server's /www folder. After that I typed localhost/WordPress/wp-admin it loaded the first page I clicked next. After that, it shows this page I fill in my details but on the next page, I get this error. I am new to WordPress any help will be appreciated. I have created the database in myphpadmin with the name, and my username is "root" with no password
[image: First Page where I enter my data]
[image: Error]

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the second screenshot and looked at the wp-config.php file?

Comment: Yes, I did look at the wp-config.php file it's all ok I even reinstalled WordPress couple times now